# Check if list of array exists in the array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, underscore.js

I have the following array

```
var data  = ["004", "456", "333", "555"];
```

I also have an  array of object like this.

```
Object {Results:Array[2]}
Results:Array[2]
    [0-1]
         0:Object
           id="004"     
           name: "Rick"
           Active: "false"
         1:Object
           id="005"     
           name:'david'
           Active: "false"
```

As you can see, id with 004 consists in array as well as in object. I want to check how many elements from the array 'data' are present in the object 'Results.

The final result should be

```
data = ["004"];
```

Can anyone let me know how to search for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without underscore.js

```js
var data = ["004", "456", "333", "555"];
arr = [{
  id: "004",
  name: "Rick",
  Active: "false"
}, {
  id: "005",
  name: 'david',
  Active: "false"
}];

out = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
    if (arr[i].id === data[j])
      out.push(data[j]);
  }
}
console.log(out);
```

With underscore.js

```js
var data = ["004", "456", "333", "555"];
arr = [{
  id: "004",
  name: "Rick",
  Active: "false"
}, {
  id: "005",
  name: 'david',
  Active: "false"
}];

out = [];

_.each(arr, function(value1, key1, obj1) {
  _.each(data, function(value, key, obj) {
    if (value1.id == value) out.push(value);
  });
});

console.log(out);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Mahi- Can you also let me know what changes i will have to make if i want the unmatched elements of 'data' in 'arr'

Comment: you want only id in arr ??

Comment: @Mahi- as shown above, 004 will be the output since that is the only value which is present in 'arr'. I want the output to be ['456', '333', '555'] indicating that these values are not present in 'arr'. any idea how to achieve this ?

Comment: @AduRao you want to remove result from data array ?

Comment: @AduRao in that case use `out = _.without(data, out[0]);`  using without underscore method

Answer (score 0):

I guess the following code (not tested)

```
l_return = [];
for (l_cnt = 0; l_cnt < Results.length - 1; l_cnt++) {
    if (data.indexof(Result[l_cnt].id) != -1) l_return.push(Result[l_cnt].id)
}
data = l_return
```

Comment: Don't forget to use `var` unless you really want globals.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you what you are looking for.

```js
var data  = ["004", "456", "333", "555"];
var results = [
  {
    id: "004",
    name: "Rick",
    Active: "false"
  },{
    id: "005",
    name: "david",
    Active: "false"
  }
];


var found = [];
results.forEach(i => {
  if(data.includes(i.id)){
    if(!found.includes(i.id)) found.push(i.id);
  }
});

console.log(found) // ["004"]
```